# what directory is used to execute "expr" command,what holds it process-id and log record

Tags: proc, variable

What directory execute the expr command. What directory holds the the PID of the command. What directory hold the log file of this command.and how to read all these??

Comment: You want something from us. A question should make the readers feel like helping. Do you think yours does?

Comment: Sorry for the mistyping on the title.. Won't happen further. Sry for the inconvenience anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Linux is file based. So everything is a file and you read it as a file.

The commands that you run come either from the shell itself, as in built-in commands like cd, or from `$PATH`.

```
echo $PATH # Will return the PATH that the shell will look in for the command you just tried to run
```

Your shell will actually search `$PATH` for the command you issued and if it finds it, it will run it, if it doesn't it will give you an error. A command is an application by itself, unless it's built-in into the shell like `cd`.

You can find where an application is by using the `whereis` command.

```
whereis ls
```

The **PID** and all the information about each **process** is in `/proc`. A **command** does not have a **PID** a **process** does.

The logs are generally saved in `/var/log/`

There are no **log files** for a command unless the application saves its own logs in its own home configuration directory or it's a service that logs to `/var/log/`. You can redirect the output of a command to a file if you so wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. It is very much helpful.. Can u just explain the "echo$path " plzz. Amd as per I knw cd, ls commands root directory file is /bin.. I wanna kwhats the directory for expr command (if any). Thnx again for ur answer buddy :D

Comment: as I said above, `cd` is a built-in command in your shell, `ls` is not, it is in **$PATH**. The **root directory** is actually `/`

Comment: Thnx a lot.. Its more than enough for now. :)

Comment: Bro, i just typed in "whereis expr" command and it shows as this - expr:/usr/bin/expr/usr/share/man/man1/expr.1.gz         .Again, typing "whereis grep" results - grep:/bin/grep  .

Comment: Yes, that is where expr exists and where its man pages are. So ?

Comment: Ok bro.. That's it.. Thnx for ur patience. Now I have better view. Didn't know questioning on this site can work so efficiently & quickly :O .. Amazed !! Praise worthy (Y)